# Передача списка в filter queryset

Tags: python, django

Есть список `item_list = ['bow','axe' 'dagger'......]`.
Необходимо передать этот список в `filter django`.
Пробовал `Item.objects.filter(item_id=item_list)` Но тогда возвращается пустой `queryset`.
Как можно реализовать?

Comment: `Item.objects.filter(item_id__in=item_list)`

Answer (score 0):

AndreyMaslov предложил способ.

```
Item.objects.filter(item_id__in=item_list)
```